# Dynamically add facebook like button using jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook, dynamic, facebook-like

How can i dynamically add facebook like button using jquery?
I'm planning to have a gallery and want to add add like buttons under every image?
I've tried this but it doesn't render anything:
**$('.share_button').append("(fb:like layout='button_count' font='tahoma')(/fb:like)")**
where share_button is a classname of div tag that will contain the like button.

Thanks in advance,
Ivan

Answer (score 7):

First of all, it should be:

```
$('.share_button').append("<fb:like layout='button_count' font='tahoma'></fb:like>")
```

Then, you should add this line:

```
FB.XFBML.parse($('.share_button').get(0));
```

However, I suggest you to use ID instead of class, or the codes above will parse all nodes containing class `.share_button`.

Comment: answer is good, but to avoid memory leaks, add `$('.share_button').empty()` before appending or updating its innerHTML if you don't need the like button(s) anymore. my experience in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You also should have

> xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"

and after you should parse FB tags that you add after page was loaded. It was previously answered [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305658/facebook-tags-dont-render-when-generated-dynamically-using-jquery)